# My google map won't show every mark

Tags: javascript, marker

heey everybody,
i need to make a google map with the markers of our customers
however i'm not good at programming still at school and not really getting much programming :(
however my problem is that i'm able to get a few markers on the map however not all of them and it always is a different amount that will show. i'm working adress based not with lat and longtitude.

here is my script

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAjU0EJWnWPMv7oQ-jjS7dYxTPZYElJSBeBUeMSX5xXgq6lLjHthSAk20WnZ_iuuzhMt60X_ukms-AUg"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

        //load Google Map
        function load() {
          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl()); 
                map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); 

        //create randomnumber to prevent caching and retrieve xml file
        //data.xml vervangen door weg naar .xml bestand
        GDownloadUrl("data.xml", function(data, responseCode) {
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);

        //store markers in markers array
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        //while loop ipv for loop
        var i = 0
        do
            {
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
            showAddress(map,geocoder,address,html);
            timer();
            }
        while (i <= 18);


            function timer()
        {
        i++
        setTimeout("timer()",1000);
        }

        //Create marker and set up event window
        function createMarker(point,html){
          var marker = new GMarker(point);
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
             marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
          });
          return marker;
        }

        //showAddress
        function showAddress(map,geocoder,address,html) {
          geocoder.getLatLng(
            address,
            function(point) {
              if (!point) {
                alert(address + " niet gevonden");
              } else {
                map.setCenter(point, 12);
                var marker = createMarker(point,html+'<br/><br/>'+address);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
              }
            }
          );
        }


          }
        ); //close GDownloadUrl
  } //close GBrowserIsCompatible
} //close load
   //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 700px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the Google API throttling the number of queries you can make. If you ask it for locations of addresses too quickly then it will deny you after the first few requests.

I see you've tried to get around this with your `timer()` function, but the way you've written it won't actually delay the `while` loop (Javascript will set the timer then happily continue to the next iteration of the loop). What you need to do is bring the calls to the API inside the code that gets called by `setTimeout`, like this:

```
function placeMarker(i) {

    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address"),
        html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");

    showAddress(map,geocoder,address,html);

    if (++i <= 18) {

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                placeMarker(i);
            },
            1000
        );

    }

}

placeMarker(0);
```

Comment: thx this works :D
thank you very much have been busy with this for the last 3 days now :P

Comment: No problem. Took me ages to figure out the first time I came across it as well!

Comment: is there maybe also a way to speed this up? cuz i need to get 6k markers on there and like this way the fastest possible is around 20 mins xD